# Why does accessing a non-existing element of an awk array create this element?

Tags: awk

I just spent a lot of time on a piece of awk code whose behavior I do not understand: if an array does NOT contain an element, why does trying to access this element creates it (with an empty value)?

```sh
echo "1" | awk '{a[$1]=12} END{for (i in a) {print i,a[i]}; print a[2]; for (i in a) {print i,a[i]};}'
```

returns

```
1 12

1 12  
2
```

The element "2" has been created in a[] with the value "". Does this mean that you have to test if any element exists before accessing it, otherwise taking the risk of altering your array size. That seems a quite dangerous behaviour. (I am using gawk.)

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: That's the way `awk` works. That's why if you use `i in a` to check for existence before accessing `a[i]` you can determine whether or not it exists before creating it. `print a[2]` will create the element.

Comment: From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Variables): "There is no need to explicitly initialize a variable in `awk`, which is what you would do in C and in most other traditional languages."

Comment: 1) `The element "2" has been created in a[] with the value ""` - no, it's been created with the value zero-or-null just like an uninitialized scalar variable. 2) `Does this mean that you have to test if any element exists before accessing it` - if you need to not create the element  then yes, otherwise no. 3) `That seems a quite dangerous behaviour.` - meh, it's fine.

Comment: as everyone has said, that is expected behavior from `awk`. The provided solution is to test with `if (elem in arr) { print arr[elem]}`. Good luck.

Comment: What I meant is that it makes sense that attributing a value to a[i] creates the element. That **reading** it does the same seems dangerous to me, i.e. that the test `if (elem in arr)` becomes true. 

To give the context, I was summing data over existing nearest neighbors in a lattice and updating existing sites. By summing over non-existing elements, I created them and they were later updated, leading to a bug. I fixed it by adding a test `if (elem in arr)` but this was unexpected behavior for me. (Even knowing that "There is no need to explicitly initialize a variable in `awk`".)